# Are there any puranas about Satya Yuga?

Tags: puranas, bhagavata-purana, yuga

I have a feeling that all puranas which describe events happened in Satya yuga talk about events happened in other lokas, different from Bhumi (our planet). I personally know only one purana which talks about events which *for sure* happened in Satya yuga: Bhagavata purana, canto 7, talks about Narasimha avatara, and events there presumably happened here on Earth, but I am not sure. Ramayana is about Treta yuga, and Mahabaharata together with Bhagavata purana canto 10 talks about Dvapara yuga.

Am I wrong? Are there any other puranas which talk about events happened in Satya yuga here on Earth?

Comment: So to be clear, you're not interested in a description of what the Satya Yuga is like, but rather a description of what specific events happened in the last Satya Yuga?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yes, exactly. I have some good understanding about what Satya Yuga is like, but some specific stories about life of humans on Earth in this era would be interesting. I think.

Comment: OK, let me try to find out about that.  There's lots of scriptures that talk about the first Satya Yuga of the present Kalpa, but there doesn't seem to be that much information about what happened in the most recent Satya Yuga (i.e. the 28th Satya Yuga of the Vaivasvata Manvanthara.) I did find a story about a camel who stretched his neck too far: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a111.htm

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I guess in the scriptures about first Satya Yuga of the present Kalpa there's mostly stories about *deva*s, not about life of people in human bodies on Earth, right?